# How can I place two DIVs inside a horizontal fixed header and make all the content vertically align?

Tags: css, html

I have a fixed header working as a menu. In this header, I want to show the logo (on the left) and the navigation (on the right). Both will be fixed as I scroll the page.

My navigation is already working. How can I place another DIV for my logo?

Also, how can I make all this content (logo and navigation) vertically align?

Preview: http://baskra.com/teste/teste.html

Here's what I tried, but it didn't work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>bask.ra</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900,200italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- COMECO DO NIVO SLIDER -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- FIM DO NIVO SLIDER -->

<!-- COMECO DO MENU FIXO -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("document").ready(function($){

    var nav = $('.menu-fundo');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
            nav.addClass("f-menu");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("f-menu");
        }
    });

});
</script>
<!-- FIM DO MENU FIXO -->

</head>

<body>

<div class="menu-fundo">
<div class="menu">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>

<div class="logo">

<img src="images/logo.png" />

</div>

        <ul id="menutop">
              <li><a href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
              <li><a href="#equipe">EQUIPE</a></li>
              <li><a href="#quem">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#como">COMO FAZEMOS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#que">O QUE FAZEMOS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

<script>
$("#menutop a").click(function(){
   var menuid = $(this).attr("href");
   $("body").animate({scrollTop: $(menuid).offset().top - $('.menu').height() }, "slow");
   return false;
});
</script>

<div class="elementos">

<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider theme-default">
    <img src="images/slide1.png"/>
    <img src="images/slide2.png"/>
    <img src="images/slide3.png"/>
</div>



<div class="o-que-fazemos">
  <a id="que"></a>
    O QUE FAZEMOS?<br />
<br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
<br />
Vivamus mollis sed lectus nec malesuada. Maecenas luctus suscipit varius. Sed bibendum luctus ligula, fermentum venenatis arcu interdum eu. Praesent sollicitudin tortor arcu, eu varius nulla consectetur ac. Etiam vel interdum urna. Sed dignissim, quam eu consectetur dictum, felis nulla suscipit dolor, ut tincidunt lorem nisi ut nibh. Mauris aliquam laoreet leo, id bibendum arcu ornare vel. Vivamus ultricies fermentum porta. Praesent et mi tortor. Quisque varius mi ac nibh ultricies, id faucibus orci semper. Maecenas sit amet consectetur purus. Quisque vulputate in felis sit amet convallis. Sed pellentesque, lacus in auctor tincidunt, eros quam pellentesque magna, at rhoncus nulla mauris quis lorem. Maecenas condimentum massa ut bibendum sagittis. Etiam non fringilla felis.
<br />
Curabitur rhoncus ut nibh eget interdum. Donec gravida, nunc gravida egestas tempus, leo urna vulputate ipsum, eget euismod leo enim et mi. Quisque non adipiscing nisi. Morbi a odio non lorem sagittis egestas vel et nunc. Vestibulum et turpis egestas neque blandit porttitor. Phasellus sem tellus, elementum id odio eget, scelerisque tincidunt lectus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus malesuada bibendum leo sit amet commodo. Vivamus vestibulum pulvinar nisl, eget scelerisque est dictum vel. Pellentesque posuere mattis ante, quis venenatis augue. Sed malesuada risus elit, vitae bibendum mi porta nec. Ut vitae purus felis. 
<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.

</div>

<div class="como-fazemos">
  <a id="como"></a>
  <h1 class="como-fazemos-title">COMO FAZEMOS?</h1>

<p align="center"><img src="images/comofazemos.png" /></p>

</div>

<div class="quem-somos">
  <a id="quem"></a>
  QUEM SOMOS?<br />
<br />

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
<br />
Vivamus mollis sed lectus nec malesuada. Maecenas luctus suscipit varius. Sed bibendum luctus ligula, fermentum venenatis arcu interdum eu. Praesent sollicitudin tortor arcu, eu varius nulla consectetur ac. Etiam vel interdum urna. Sed dignissim, quam eu consectetur dictum, felis nulla suscipit dolor, ut tincidunt lorem nisi ut nibh. Mauris aliquam laoreet leo, id bibendum arcu ornare vel. Vivamus ultricies fermentum porta. Praesent et mi tortor. Quisque varius mi ac nibh ultricies, id faucibus orci semper. Maecenas sit amet consectetur purus. Quisque vulputate in felis sit amet convallis. Sed pellentesque, lacus in auctor tincidunt, eros quam pellentesque magna, at rhoncus nulla mauris quis lorem. Maecenas condimentum massa ut bibendum sagittis. Etiam non fringilla felis.
<br />
Curabitur rhoncus ut nibh eget interdum. Donec gravida, nunc gravida egestas tempus, leo urna vulputate ipsum, eget euismod leo enim et mi. Quisque non adipiscing nisi. Morbi a odio non lorem sagittis egestas vel et nunc. Vestibulum et turpis egestas neque blandit porttitor. Phasellus sem tellus, elementum id odio eget, scelerisque tincidunt lectus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus malesuada bibendum leo sit amet commodo. Vivamus vestibulum pulvinar nisl, eget scelerisque est dictum vel. Pellentesque posuere mattis ante, quis venenatis augue. Sed malesuada risus elit, vitae bibendum mi porta nec. Ut vitae purus felis. 
<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
</div>

<div class="a-equipe">
  <a id="equipe"></a>
  EQUIPE<br />
<br />

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
<br />
Vivamus mollis sed lectus nec malesuada. Maecenas luctus suscipit varius. Sed bibendum luctus ligula, fermentum venenatis arcu interdum eu. Praesent sollicitudin tortor arcu, eu varius nulla consectetur ac. Etiam vel interdum urna. Sed dignissim, quam eu consectetur dictum, felis nulla suscipit dolor, ut tincidunt lorem nisi ut nibh. Mauris aliquam laoreet leo, id bibendum arcu ornare vel. Vivamus ultricies fermentum porta. Praesent et mi tortor. Quisque varius mi ac nibh ultricies, id faucibus orci semper. Maecenas sit amet consectetur purus. Quisque vulputate in felis sit amet convallis. Sed pellentesque, lacus in auctor tincidunt, eros quam pellentesque magna, at rhoncus nulla mauris quis lorem. Maecenas condimentum massa ut bibendum sagittis. Etiam non fringilla felis.
<br />
Curabitur rhoncus ut nibh eget interdum. Donec gravida, nunc gravida egestas tempus, leo urna vulputate ipsum, eget euismod leo enim et mi. Quisque non adipiscing nisi. Morbi a odio non lorem sagittis egestas vel et nunc. Vestibulum et turpis egestas neque blandit porttitor. Phasellus sem tellus, elementum id odio eget, scelerisque tincidunt lectus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus malesuada bibendum leo sit amet commodo. Vivamus vestibulum pulvinar nisl, eget scelerisque est dictum vel. Pellentesque posuere mattis ante, quis venenatis augue. Sed malesuada risus elit, vitae bibendum mi porta nec. Ut vitae purus felis. 
<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
</div>

<div class="o-contato">
  <a id="contato"></a>
  CONTATO<br />
<br />

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
<br />
Vivamus mollis sed lectus nec malesuada. Maecenas luctus suscipit varius. Sed bibendum luctus ligula, fermentum venenatis arcu interdum eu. Praesent sollicitudin tortor arcu, eu varius nulla consectetur ac. Etiam vel interdum urna. Sed dignissim, quam eu consectetur dictum, felis nulla suscipit dolor, ut tincidunt lorem nisi ut nibh. Mauris aliquam laoreet leo, id bibendum arcu ornare vel. Vivamus ultricies fermentum porta. Praesent et mi tortor. Quisque varius mi ac nibh ultricies, id faucibus orci semper. Maecenas sit amet consectetur purus. Quisque vulputate in felis sit amet convallis. Sed pellentesque, lacus in auctor tincidunt, eros quam pellentesque magna, at rhoncus nulla mauris quis lorem. Maecenas condimentum massa ut bibendum sagittis. Etiam non fringilla felis.
<br />
Curabitur rhoncus ut nibh eget interdum. Donec gravida, nunc gravida egestas tempus, leo urna vulputate ipsum, eget euismod leo enim et mi. Quisque non adipiscing nisi. Morbi a odio non lorem sagittis egestas vel et nunc. Vestibulum et turpis egestas neque blandit porttitor. Phasellus sem tellus, elementum id odio eget, scelerisque tincidunt lectus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus malesuada bibendum leo sit amet commodo. Vivamus vestibulum pulvinar nisl, eget scelerisque est dictum vel. Pellentesque posuere mattis ante, quis venenatis augue. Sed malesuada risus elit, vitae bibendum mi porta nec. Ut vitae purus felis. 
<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


html,body {
    height:100%;    
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    }

div {
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    }

logo {  
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    z-index:9999;
    float:left;
    }

.menu-fundo {
    background: #fff repeat-x 0 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    position:fixed;
    }

.f-menu {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    } /* isso vai fazer o menu ficar fixo no topo */

.menu {
height: 100px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index:
9999;
background: #fff repeat-x 0 0;
position:fixed; width:100%
}

.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }

.menu ul li {
float: right;
padding-right:30px;
padding-top:0px;
}

.menu ul li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
    }

.menu ul li a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-top:3px solid #999;
    }

.menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #6D6D6D;
    border-top:3px solid #EA0000;
    }

.o-que-fazemos {
    background-image: url('images/oqfazemosFUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.como-fazemos {
    background-image: url('images/comofazemosFUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.como-fazemos-title {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;

    }

.quem-somos {
    background-image: url('images/quemsomosFUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.a-equipe {
    background-image: url('images/EQUIPE-FUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.o-contato {
    background-image: url('images/contato-FUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.banner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    }

.banner li {
    list-style: none;
    }

.banner ul li {
    float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some styles to `.menu ul`

```
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;

    /* add this */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you very much. How can I vertically align both logo and navigation?

Comment: hacky way, increase the top value: `top: 25px;`

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to use css table display to vertically align elements. Additionally menu will not be over the logo on smaller screens.

```
.login {
  display: table-cell;
}

.menu ul {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I did this, but it didn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: First you have to remove styles added in previous answer.